# Trouble understanding basic of Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is the forms.py file:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    data = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def clean(self):
        #super(MyForm, self).clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            print self.errors
            return
        value = self.cleaned_data['data']
        if int(value)%2 != 0:
            print "invalid data"
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please enter an even number"))
```

This is my view.py file:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("thanks")
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'todayhome.html', context)
```

And this is my todayhome.html file:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
{{authorformset}}
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

What I don't understand is :

1. Do I need to call

   ```
   super(MyForm, self).clean()
   ```

inside 'clean' method of forms.py explicitly, or will it be called automatically once I do

```
    self.errors?
```

2. If I remove

   ```
   if any(self.errors):
       print self.errors
       return
   ```

   from the 'clean' method of forms.py file and submit the form empty, it renders shows

   ```
    'KeyError (data)'
   ```

instead of showing 'This field is required.' Why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to call `super(MyForm, self).clean()` inside 'clean' method of forms.py explicitly, or will it be called automatically once I do

You need to call it explicitly. That is the method which populates the `self.errors` attribute, when some error is found. Using `self.errors` you're just accessing that attribute, not calling any method.

For your second question, it shows `KeyError` while accessing `self.cleaned_data['data']` (in case when you call super clean method), because when a particular key is added to `self.errors`, it is not added to `self.cleaned_data`. You need to check the key existence or `self.errors` first, before accessing any `cleaned_data` key.

Comment: and what about "self.is_valid()", does it calls super(MyForm, self).clean() internally ?

Comment: @SumitJha `self.is_valid()` is what that calls `clean()` method. If you override that, your overridden method will be called. You've to call super class `clean()` method explicitly from overridden method, else it would never be called.